# How to solve this system of four non-linear equations: $a+b=1, a x+b y=\frac{1}{2}, a x^2+b y^2=\frac{1}{3}, a x^3+b y^3=\frac{1}{4}$

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I've tried a lot of substitutions and combinations of equations to manually solve this system for $a$, $b$, $x$, $y$, however nothing seems to bring me closer to a solution.

\begin{align*}
a + b &= 1 \tag{1}\\
a x + b y &= \frac{1}{2} \tag{2}\\
a x^2 + b y^2 &= \frac{1}{3} \tag{3}\\
a x^3 + b y^3 &= \frac{1}{4} \tag{4}\\
\end{align*}

In case it matters, I'm trying to calculate the points and weights of a [Gaussian quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature) with $n=2$. I'm aware the manual solving would become easier for integrating in $(-1, 1)$ instead of $(0, 1)$, however if possible I'd like to learn how to solve the exact system above. Expected solution is $a=\frac{1}{2}$, $b=\frac{1}{2}$, $x=\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}$, $y=\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}$. WolframAlpha link is [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%2Bb%3D1%20and%20a*x%2Bb*y%3D1%2F2%20and%20a*x%5E2%2Bb*y%5E2%3D1%2F3%20and%20a*x%5E3%2Bb*y%5E3%3D1%2F4).

Comment: Typo in (4) - $by^3$ instead of $bx^3$?

Comment: @TokenToucan thanks, indeed

Comment: See https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/1990_AIME_Problems/Problem_15 maybe.

Comment: @MaxD: If we eliminate stuff, we end up with $$6 y^2-6 y + 1 = 0$$

Comment: @Moo can you elaborate a bit on how to get to this?

Comment: @JetChung Wow thats really similar, how did you find this?

Comment: @MaxD I used to do a lot of competition math in high school :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
(1)x-(2)\Rightarrow b(x-y)&=x-\frac{1}{2}\tag{5}\\
(2)x-(3)\Rightarrow by(x-y)&=\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{3}\tag{6}\\
(3)x-(4)\Rightarrow by^2(x-y)&=\frac{x}{3}-\frac{1}{4}\tag{7}\\
(5)\rightarrow(6)\Rightarrow y(x-\frac{1}{2})&=\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{3}\tag{8}\\
(6)\rightarrow(7)\Rightarrow y(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{3})&=\frac{x}{3}-\frac{1}{4}\tag{9}\\
\frac{(8)}{(9)}\Rightarrow \frac{x-\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{3}}&=\frac{\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{3}}{\frac{x}{3}-\frac{1}{4}}\\
6x^2-6x+1&=0
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Is your numbering off by one? Should start at 5 and not 4 if I'm not missing anything?

Comment: Thanks  for reminding  numbering

Comment: @MaxD  thanks for editing.

Answer (score 1):

$\require{begingroup} \begingroup$
$\def\e{\mathrm{e}}$

> \begin{align}a + b &= 1 \tag{1}\label{1},\\ a x + b y &= \frac{1}{2} \tag{2}\label{2},\\ a  x^2 + b y^2 &= \frac{1}{3} \tag{3}\label{3},\\ a x^3 + b y^3 &=\frac{1}{4} \tag{4}\label{4}.\end{align}

The system of \eqref{1}-\eqref{4} is perfectly suitable for
[Prony's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prony%27s_method).

\begin{align}
a\, \e^{0\cdot\lambda_x} + b\,\e^{0\cdot\lambda_x} &= 1 
\tag{5}\label{5}
,\\
a\, \e^{1\cdot\lambda_x} + b\, \e^{1\cdot\lambda_y} &= \frac{1}{2} 
\tag{6}\label{6}
,\\
a\, \e^{2\cdot\lambda_x} + b\, \e^{2\cdot\lambda_y} &= \frac{1}{3} 
\tag{7}\label{7}
,\\
a\, \e^{3\cdot\lambda_x} + b\, \e^{3\cdot\lambda_y}  &= \frac{1}{4} 
\tag{8}\label{8}
,
\end{align}

where $\lambda_x=\ln x$,
$\lambda_y=\ln y$.

The pair $x,y$ is found as a solution to quadratic equation

\begin{align} 
z^2-a_0\,z-a_1&=0
\tag{9}\label{9}
,
\end{align}

where

\begin{align} 
\begin{bmatrix} a_0 \\ a_1 \end{bmatrix}
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
1/2 & 1 \\
1/3 & 1/2
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix} 1/3 \\ 1/4 \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-6 & 12 \\
4 & -6
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 1/3 \\ 1/4 \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1/6 \end{bmatrix}
\tag{10}\label{10}
,
\end{align}

so \eqref{9} becomes
\begin{align} 
z^2-z+\frac16&=0
\tag{11}\label{11}
,\\
x,y&=\frac12 \pm \frac{\sqrt3}6
\tag{12}\label{12}
.
\end{align}

And from the $2\times2$ system \eqref{1}, \eqref{2},

\begin{align}
a &= \tfrac12\cdot\frac{1-2y}{x-y}
=\frac12
\tag{13}\label{13}
,\\
b &= \tfrac12\cdot\frac{2x-1}{x-y}
=\frac12
\tag{14}\label{14}
.
\end{align}

$\endgroup$